# Chrome Extension: Page monitoring gets disabled

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I recently built a Chrome Extension to monitor changes in some web-pages. The Extension locates the object being monitored every 2 seconds or so by XPath, reads the content and compares whether it is different from previous value and sends a signal to an URL.

It works well, however, if I minimize Chrome, change to another Tab or place the Chrome window at the background (Z-Level), then the Extensions seems to do nothing, the monitoring stops. When I activate the Chrome window again and make it visible, then the monitoring starts working again.

How can I prevent Chrome from disabling the Extension when it is in the background or minimized?

The monitoring is implemented using:

```
var id = setInterval(async () => {
  {
    var element = getElementByXpath(xpath);
    // some code
  }
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Chrome throttles timers in inactive tabs to one run per minute. You can call setInterval in the background script instead, and send a message to the content script which will do getElementByXpath.

Comment: @wOxxOm But in the background, how could the Extension discriminate which web-page it is currently monitoring? The Extension may be monitoring multiple web-pages at the same time.

Comment: The content script does chrome.runtime.sendMessage, the background script listens via chrome.runtime.onMessage which receives `sender` with tab id inside.

Comment: @wOxxOm Is there any way you could illustrate your suggestion better? I am trying to read the document from Background, but it won't read.

Comment: The background would only have setInterval + chrome.tabs.sendMessage inside. Anyway, there's a better method: `MutationObserver`.